# Excel - Passing a parameter into a custom query

Tags: excel, parameters, powerquery

Hi i am trying to create a table in excel with a parameter from a cell.

as you can see from the image below i am trying to change the value 7006 into a variable parameter.

If anyone could help me it would be appreciated.

**I have blocked out the Server and Database Name.**

[image]

I now get this error: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open extended editor and replace 7006 by this

```
"& ContactIDP &"
```

So your code should look like this

```
... WHERE (ContactID = "& ContactIDP &"))) OR ...
```

This will concatenate your ID to SQL-query. Make shure that your parameter's type is text. Otherwise apply Text.From() function

```
... WHERE (ContactID = "& Text.From(ContactIDP) &"))) OR ...
```

Comment: I cant seem to get this to work - I have edited the question to show what error your solution shows.